# C# - Design Problem Advice: Can't Use Dictionary then what?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services

I need to return a Dictionary (or some List, I just don't know) via a web service, specifically through a WCF Data Services.  It looks like WCF Data Services does not support Dictionary types.

Something to look like this via the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <Employees xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
    <element>employee1, True</element> 
    <element>employee2, False</element>
    <element>employee3, True</element>
  </Employees>
```

I first tried a 1-dimensional array and this seems to work but of course only brings those 1 dimensional array with 3 elemetns:

```
[WebGet]
public string[] Employees()
{
   return new[]
   {
        "employee1",
        "employee2",
        "employee3"
   };
}
```

Basically, I need some List (?) with two parameters in each, that is, EmployeeName and a booleann value, IsActive.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Update: I added the following to my web service:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public bool IsActive{ get; set; }

        public Employee(string name, bool isActive)
        {
            Name = name;
            IsActive = isActive;
        }
    }

[WebGet]
        public List<Employee> Employees()
        {
            var emp1 = new Employee("Test1", true);
            var emp2 = new Employee("Test2", true);
            var list = new List<Employee> { emp1, emp2 };
            return list;
        }
```

And when like the .svc file via my web browser, I get this on load:

```
Request Error

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Unable to load metadata for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Web.Employee]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[.Web.Employee] Employees()'.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: 

at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.AddServiceOperation(MethodInfo method, String protocolMethod) at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.AddOperationsFromType(Type type) at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody) at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Any ideas?

Update 2:

Here is more information on my DataService.svc class.  I am using V2 of WCF Data Services with the .NET 4.0 framework:

```
public class WebDataService : DataService<MyModelEntities>
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead | EntitySetRights.AllWrite);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }
```

Comment: @user118190 this works fine in VS 2010 using .net 4.0.  What version of the framework are you using ?

Comment: @JonH - Really?? I have updated my original question with "Update 2".  I've been using this web data service for over 2 years.  First it was a v1 of WCF DS and then moved over to v2 once .NET 4.0 got released.  I too am using VS 2010.  I just encountered this error when I wanted to create a custom [WebGet] method and it seems to not like it.  Thanks for all your insight and assistance!

Answer (score 6):

Why dont you just create a user defined data type with two attributes a string and a boolean?

```
public class MySillyWCFObject
{ 
 boolean b;
 string name;

 public MySillyWCFObject(boolean b, string s)
  {
   this.b = b;
   this.name = s;
  }
}
```

Then you can say:

```
MySillyWCFObject m = new MySillyWCFObject(true, "Hi");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I added the code, I in turn added a quick snippet: //[WebGet]
        public List<Employee> Employees()
        {
            var ex1 = new Employee("Test1", true);
            var ex2 = new Employee("Test1", true);
            var list = new List<Employee> {ex1, ex2};
            return list;
        }   The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Unable to load metadata for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Employee]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Employee] Employees()'.'.

Comment: @user118190 - I'm not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I added a [WebGet] method, public List<Employee> Employees() and I got the above error.  For some reason, my WCF Data Service is not parsing it.

Comment: @user118190 - Please edit your original question with your new code and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to create your own class just for this, you can use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create(true, "Hi");
```

This will create a `Tuple<bool, string>` by inferring the types from the method call's parameters. You can then access `true` and `"Hi"` as `Tuple.Item1` and `Tuple.Item2`.

Comment: yes a tuple works great but he would need to put them in a list to get what he wants.  but Tuple isn't that robust.  I don't like them personally.

Comment: @phillip: The list part is kind of obvious :) But why do you say that it isn't robust?

Comment: @Jon I somewhat agree with phillip, I dislike losing my meaningful names in switching to a tuple sometimes.

Comment: @Jon in most cases keyvaluepairs are much better for performance when creating a lot of instances.  But of course when passing to functions the tuple seems to be a bit quicker.  My issue is the values in a tuple cannot be modified.  Its still a good container and might fit well with the above question.

Comment: i agree with you @asawyer and you have limitations on the DataType that can be used. Just use them and you will find several oddities that are present.

Comment: Readability may be an issue as well. When I do `Tuple<bool, string> t = new Tuple<bool, string>(true, "hi"); t.Item1;` to me what is Item1? It becomes difficult to read. If we could really get them to change this then it might be easier...something like a named parameter type.

Comment: @JonH, @philip: You should not examine this out of context. A `Tuple<DateTime, double>` might not say much, but if it's in a list called `GrossSalesPerDay` I think you will get the picture.

Comment: @Jon The picture can be seen much more clearly using other types.  Anyone using Linq with these get's tired of them very quickly which is why they haven't caught on.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this before [How to Return Generic Dictionary in a WebService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679050/how-to-return-generic-dictionary-in-a-webservice/1280628#1280628).

It is code to provide you with a serializable dictionary.  It works great.  We have a real-time system which passes these around and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a little transfer object class like:

```
[DataContract]
public class EmployeeDTO {

public EmployeeDTO(string empName,bool isActive){
   EmployeeName = empName;
   IsActive = isActive;
}
[DataMember]
public string EmployeeName {get;private set;}
[DataMember]
public bool IsActive {get;private set;}

}
```

---

your service method

```
[WebGet]
public EmployeeDTO[] Employees(){
 return new []{new EmployeeDTO("employee1",true),
               new EmployeeDTO("employee2",false),
               new EmployeeDTO("employee3",true),};
}
```

Comment: @user118190 - These are examples use the examples to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I added your code and am getting the following via my .svc call:....  The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Unable to load metadata for return type 'Web.DataService+EmployeeDTO[]' of method 'EmployeeDTO[] Employees()'.' –

Comment: seems to be a known issue please refer this forum thread. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/98f17332-3992-427b-b454-617677dea9c7

Comment: Hmmm... interesting, I will explore this further and report on my findings.  Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try returning IQueryable instead of List? Your return statement will change to `return list.AsQueryable();` in that case. Also, you will need to add [DataServiceKey] attribute to the Employee class (e.g. [DataServiceKey("Name")]).