# Convert JSON to XML using JavaScriptSerializer in c#

Tags: c#, xml, json

I have a JSON structure like below.

```
json={
    "page": {
        "mode": "2",
        "ref": "user"
    }
}
```

I am using the following code for converting JSON to XML.

Reference:
http://www.flowgearcoder.net/2013/04/03/convert-between-json-and-xml

```
  var dynamicObject = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(Json);
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(dynamicObject.GetType());

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(ms, dynamicObject);

        Xml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

I am getting the following error while executing the xmlSerializer conversion.

> The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089], [System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is
>   not supported because it implements IDictionary.

Can anyone help me figure out this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to XML? Just asking because in a previous question someone wanted to convert to XML first, then deserialize the xml into objects. If this is your plan you are better off deserializing the json itself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679050/how-to-return-generic-dictionary-in-a-webservice See this earlier QA for info

Comment: @havardhu, I want to convert JSON to HTML. SO in first step i will convert JSON to XML and then to HTML. Can you identify the issue?

Comment: @Precious1tj, why you mentioned the URL that i added for reference in my question itself?

Comment: Can you post your json string?

Comment: I suspect the object in json is a dictionary type object, while the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` does not support serialization/deserialization of IDictionary objects.

Comment: Yes. var dynamicObject = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(Json); converts json to a dictionary object. when i check the gettype of dynamicObject.GetType() it returns dictionary.

Comment: But i suspect dynamicObject is not supported in .net 3.5. Im using the same.

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be converted to xml using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject cast json string to `Dictionary<String, Object>`.

Dictionary is not supported by XMLSerializer. So if you're creating json yourself, you might want to change its structure and use `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>` method to cast it to specific class and latter serialize it to XML.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `JavaScriptSerializer`, you may use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Xml;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"{""page"":  {""mode"": ""2"", ""ref"": ""user""}}";
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        var d=  xmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","utf-8","yes");
        xmlDocument.AppendChild(d);
        var xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
        var root = xmlDocument.ImportNode(xml.DocumentElement,true);
        xmlDocument.AppendChild(root);
        Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<page><mode>2</mode><ref>user</ref></page>
```